# Occasional error of import matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, import

In a newly created terminal, I can `import matplotlib` with no error. After working for some time in the terminal, however, the following happens:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
Usage: example.py torrentfile.torrent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 19, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import is_color_like
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/colors.py", line 54, in <module>
    import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 15, in <module>
    import new
  File "new.py", line 12, in <module>
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as fh:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Your import is invoking a program expecting input from the command line, the first argument would be `sys.argv[1]`. The real matplotlib shouldn't do this, and probably wouldn't print `Usage: example.py torrentfile.torrent`. You have a file in your python path masquerading as matplotlib.

Comment: The problem is that it is looking for a file passed (that's the `with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as fh:` bit). I don't know what file it is trying to open, but it is strange that it is using sys.argv. Also, the `import new ` seems to be specific to your version. I don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @CaptainMurphy and @IronManMark20, I discovered `new.py` and `new.pyc` under `~/temp`, which shadows some `matplotlib` files. After removing them, the problem is solved.